# remove certain items when printing a directory list

Tags: php, html, directory

i'm having the user select a specific file from a directory using a drop down menu that opens and reads a directory.

there are some items in the directory listing that shouldn't be there. items like

```
.
..
.com.apple.timemachine.supported
.DS_Store
```

how would i go about at removing these? they look like directory commands or information or something. the user shouldn't be able to select these, even though i don't think they ever would.

here is the code i'm using to read the directory and print the items into a drop down.

```
<div id='fileOpen'>    
<?
    $pathToImages = 'images/';
    $pathToVolume = '/Volumes/storage/spots_in/';

    if ($handle = opendir($pathToVolume)) {
?>
    <span class='locate'>Locate master file:</span>
    <select id='file' name='file'> 
<?
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "<option>";
        echo "$entry\n";
        echo "</option>";
    }
    closedir($handle);
 }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this

```
if (!preg_match("/^\./","$entry\n"))
```

Comment: no worries. if you only want files you could do an is_file check as well but the preg works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if (substr($entry, 0, 1) == '.') {
        continue;
    }

    /* Other stuff
}
```